# MySQL Search for Duplicates across multiple columns

Tags: mysql, duplicates

**APOLOGIES**:  I meant to say that the duplicates have to be within the same column.

I have the following code:

```
SELECT m.* FROM ( 
    SELECT text 
    FROM mytable 
    GROUP BY text 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ) q 
JOIN mytable m 
ON m.text = q.text
```

This enables me to search for duplicates on the column `text` and works fine.  However, I have a table with:

```
q1a, q2a, q3a, q4a, q5a
```

What I'd like is for the the query to check in all the columns for duplicates - if this possible and could anyone give me a pointed?

Thanks,

H.

Comment: What would be the desired result on a match on any column? Both rows containing the match with no indication of the matches?

Comment: There is an ID on the table, I'd like that to be brought back if possible?  It does this currently using the `SELECT m.*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be what you need, it will give you the text that is duplicated, and on what rows and column the match is found;

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) ids,q1a text,1 col 
FROM myTable GROUP BY text HAVING COUNT(*)>1
UNION
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id),q2a text,2 
FROM myTable GROUP BY text HAVING COUNT(*)>1
UNION
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id),q3a text,3  
FROM myTable GROUP BY text HAVING COUNT(*)>1
UNION
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id),q4a text,4  
FROM myTable GROUP BY text HAVING COUNT(*)>1
UNION
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id),q5a text,5 
FROM myTable GROUP BY text HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/27292/7).

Comment: Again, looks correct however the `id` is coming back as `[BLOB - 7B]`!?  The `id` field is the `result_id` does that make a difference?

Comment: @Homer_J Hm, what is the type of your id? :)

Comment: @Homer_J I'm not familiar with that type, nor can I change the type of `id` in the fiddle from `int` to `result_id` so I can test. Is there any documentation you can point to on that type?

Comment: Resoved it by using a different column - the code worked perfectly - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I undestand your question correctly, you could use a query like this:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM (
    SELECT txt FROM (
      SELECT q1a as txt FROM mytable
      UNION ALL
      SELECT q2a as txt FROM mytable
      UNION ALL
      SELECT q3a as txt FROM mytable
      UNION ALL
      SELECT q4a as txt FROM mytable
      UNION ALL
      SELECT q5a as txt FROM mytable) u
    GROUP BY
      txt
    HAVING COUNT(*)>1) q
  INNER JOIN mytable m
  ON q.txt IN (m.q1a, m.q2a, m.q3a, m.q4a, m.q5a)
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d6124/2).

Comment: Thanks for the reply - however, that's not correct.  The duplicates have to be in the same column.

Comment: @Homer_J what is your expected output?

Comment: @Homer_J If they're supposed to be in the same column, you may want to add that to your question.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson - where has your reply gone - that was it! :-)

Comment: @Homer_J Re-added the answer, changed to figure out duplicates per column instead of across columns. You can check history on it to get the old answer, but it had the same problem as this one, it found duplicates across all columns.